# How to get best ml model in data with not-normal right skewed distribution?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, python, scikit-learn

I am working with small amount of data: https://github.com/jeffheaton/data/blob/master/bupa.csv I want to predict y data which is drinks, who have not-normal right skewed distribution. There is a distribution and kdeplot[image: distribution]
[image: kde plot]

In almost every regression model this data have problems with fit. How to deal with data with this distribution? How to make the best model for them?
I just want to have best fit. There are two performance models that look terrible:
[image: Decision tree]
[image: Polynmial Regression]

Comment: I don't know a lot about ML, but my first thought was that the variable "number of drinks" is a count (discrete and has no negative values) and can be more accurately modeled with a Poisson distribution or some form of negative binomial regression in a typical regression model. Indeed the predictions here don't make a lot of sense...some of them are negative which is impossible. I don't know if there is an ML equivalent to that, but I would seek some way of modeling the data which incorporates this count-level information.

Comment: I also want to note that the histogram is a bit weird because you have three bars in between $0$ and $2$, which makes it appear that there are decimal values here which probably don't exist. Do people report having half drinks or one and a half drinks?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand In the raw data, many people did report 0.5 drinks.

Comment: Why does this have the machine learning tag? Also, the link just has a spreadsheet, what are the variables? Also, the final two plots aren't that useful, scatter plots of predicted vs. actual would be better.  Finally, if you could tell us what models you've tried, that would help.

Comment: @PeterFlom I'm stupid and just realized the raw data was already linked at the top so I could have already derived that there were decimal values. In any case, I do agree that additional plots and info about fitting the regression would be helpful in any regression/ML scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Often a log transform will prove handy for taming
a heavy tailed distribution, making it a little more Gaussian.
But that doesn't seem relevant here.

The [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/60/liver+disorders)
data poses some challenges for you.
Liver disease has several causes,
some due to alcohol consumption and some unrelated to that.
The dataset does not reveal whether each male subject
was diseased or healthy, nor even whether they were
of legal drinking age.

Given the paucity of data, you might be better off
posing this as a binary classification problem.
Pick some threshold number of drinks to label
each subject as a drinker or not, and call that boolean $y$.
Now use the five continuous lab result observations
to try to predict $y$.
Adjust the threshold slightly and see how the model responds.
In the case where model predicts "drinker", *then*
you might want to attempt regression on how many drinks.

Comment: I don't understand how binary classification fixes this issue when the overwhelming majority of people report drinking in the sample (the zero counts here appear very low but the binning is a bit strange to completely determine what the values actually represent). Splitting them down the middle in some other way is completely arbitrary and is consequently misleading.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand You _could_ choose a threshold level of 0.1 drinks, sure. I agree with you that it wouldn't be very useful. A level of 1.1 drinks would be better, yielding a 39% vs 61% split. But even 0.6 could be useful. Setting it at 2.1 gives roughly a 50 / 50 balanced split, suggesting that the experimenters may have viewed "above 2 drinks" as a "heavy drinker" category indicating disease risk, and they recruited balanced numbers of subjects based on that category.

Comment: The log tranform wouldnt change a resault of a model to worse?

Comment: And I just want to predict the value of drinking alcohol